# Error while creating a new project using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I installed angular-cli successfully but when I am trying to create a new project, it is throwing an error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 (node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sha1-0JydEXlkEjnRuX/8YjH9zsU+FWg= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-0JydEXlkEjnRuX/8YjH9zsU+FWg= but got sha1-Au9QsWhf0hcUTeZv8pFTf+AhiCg=. (81395 bytes)

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-5PZh90ZxHojsvqdqPJBbq/l9MVo= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-5PZh90ZxHojsvqdqPJBbq/l9MVo= but got sha1-VmZmdoabDu7UgY26v1YHr9hYUTk=. (48762 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\raman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-25T09_26_53_359Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

How do I resolve this error!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: 'npm cache clean' and install again

Comment: @Ludwig I tried your solution but the problem exists

Comment: what are your cli, npm and node.js versions?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm install
```

or also you could discard `npm` and do a

```
yarn install
```