# Creating project in Angular 6 giving error : Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: node.js, npm, angular6

I am new to `Angular`. I am facing problem in creation of project whenever I try to create project using `ng new Angular`, it ends with an error :

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ries":{},"dist":{"int'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-21T14_00_17_881Z-debug.log
>   Package install failed, see above.

I am following [this tutorial.](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/154/Angular-6-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-6-in-this-Crash-Course) I am on `windows 10` `64-bit`.

First I downloaded `Node.js` from [this URL.](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Then I checked version using `npm -v`

Then installed `angular` using `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Then I changed my directory to where I want my `Angular` project using `cd` command.

After that I entered `ng new Angular` this command.

And at last it ended with this :

```
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE Angular/angular.json (3777 bytes)
CREATE Angular/package.json (1314 bytes)
CREATE Angular/README.md (1024 bytes)
CREATE Angular/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE Angular/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
CREATE Angular/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE Angular/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/index.html (294 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/polyfills.ts (3234 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (981 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/app/app.component.ts (211 bytes)
CREATE Angular/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE Angular/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE Angular/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE Angular/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (303 bytes)
CREATE Angular/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ries":{},"dist":{"int'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-21T14_00_17_881Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

I tried:
1. Reinstalling `node.js`.
2. Running `cmd` as administrator.

What should I do now? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Regards, 
Vaibhav M

Comment: This might be resolved with the answer accepted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I solved it by observing l'll things other than `Angular`.

First: My antivirus was blocking it, so I uninstalled it. (I don't know why and how, but uninstalling my anti virus released me from some problem).

Second: Reinstalled `node.js`.

Third: I tried command given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45359620/10050369) (The `rm -rf node_modules/` command didn't worked for me so I skipped it).

And it worked like a charm for me. I posted it because may be it'll help someone.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error is caused by the firebase-admin package... still trying to figure out how to fix that though. I just have a few dependencies and I am npm-installing each of them individually.